# Transaction between accounts

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

After receiving  funds in one monero account, I transferred to other account. After few days I see that my received account shows the same balance which I have in my transferred account. If I want to transfer it again I am getting error. Is there something am I missing? I am using monero-javascript library.

Thanks

Comment: Please try and rephrase your question; it's not making a lot of sense. You mention an exchange wallet (which exchange?) but also tagged your question `monero-wallet-rpc`. You also speak of a pool address (which pool?). You lastly mention "GAS" fees but Monero doesn't have "GAS" fees.

Comment: @jtgrassie I have edited my concern. Pls help!

Comment: "I am using monero-javascript library" <- you're going to want to update the question again then showing the code you are using. Likely you're not syncing/refreshing the wallets. See https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/tree/master#sample-code